# jQuery UI Datepicker.. how to trigger AFTER the HTML has updated?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm trying to loop through all the dates in the visible calendar, using:

```
$('#datepicker table tbody td:has(a)').each(function(index) {
     ... doing stuff here with the date... (all works fine)
}
```

(this is with jQuery UI Datepicker BTW - just in case you missed it in the subject)

This works fine on the initial load. However, when you trigger **onChangeMonthYear**, it seems to run *BEFORE* the HTML for the **#datepicker** table has updated. My code is:

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    inline: true,
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    minDate: 0,
    onChangeMonthYear: function() {
        console.log("Doing update...")
        doDateUpdates();
    }
});
doDateUpdates(); // do start...

function doDateUpdates() {

    console.log($('#datepicker table tbody').html());

}
```

Here is a fiddle, so you can see it in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/fLRz6/5/

At first, I thought I was doing something wrong (as it seemed like the HTML was never changing), but after some digging - I can see that the initial + first month move, both have the same HTML... and then the 3rd month change, shows the HTML from the last slide... etc.

**UPDATE:** A kinda "workaround" I've found, is to use a setTimeout(), so my function runs 1 second after the initial function (which lets the HTML get updated)... i.e:

```
 setTimeout( function() { doDateUpdates(); }, 1000);
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing in "doing stuff here with the date"? It's possible you're attempting to solve the overall problem in the wrong way.

Comment: That part is purely for applying a different class, to dates that need to be selected. Even without that, the issue remains. One solution (if you can call it that), seems to be a timer: `setTimeout( function() { doDateUpdates(); }, 2000);` .... but I would prefer a better solution if possible. Thanks!